# Accessing alternate email addresses for a Google Account using oauth

Tags: google-oauth, openid4java

A Google account can have multiple email address associated with. e.g  abc@yahoo.com can be an email address associated with a Google account, however if a user has Gmail setup, then the Gmail address becomes the primary email address associated with that account. So in the above case, the Google account in question will have abc@gmail.com as the primary email address; and  abc@yahoo.com and abc@somenewcompany.com as secondary email addresses.

I wish to authenticate the user using abc@somenewcompany.com email address, but the token generated via Google OAuth and verified using the JSON object returned at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=generated-token only returns the primary email address.

Is there a way to identify this email address? somenewcompany.com is not a oauth provider.